# Vimperator: Entering insert mode after search

Tags: editing, vimperator

After I find some text using `/` on input field, I don't want change to insert mode when there is a match until I press c for caret mode. How can do that? Right now, press `n` for next match enters into insert mode and pressing `esc` and `n` repeatedly does not help either.

Comment: What is your question? I can not see a question mark. :-) What do you want to do?

Comment: I have gotten that same question a couple times lately. Sorry about that. I updated the question.